# cx_Oracle for Oracle Linux 7 not working after install

Tags: python, cx-oracle, oracle19c, rhel7, oraclelinux

For the last week I have been trying to get cx_oracle installed and working.
I started with an Oracle 19 appliance which is on Oracle Linux 7.
I used the official oracle site to install cx_oracle as listed below.
The install seems to have worked fine, but when I try to import the module, it is not found.
I checked all the env variables, the path, spend countless hours trying to get this work, what am I missing?
If anyone could please point me to my mistake, I would really appreciate it.
Here are all the steps I have taken so far:

Installing cx_Oracle for Python 3
To install cx_Oracle for Python 3 on Oracle Linux 7:

$ sudo yum -y install oraclelinux-developer-release-el7
$ sudo yum -y install oracle-instantclient-release-el7
$ sudo yum -y install python36-cx_Oracle
https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-python.html#cx_OraclePython3FromLatest

```
[oracle@localhost tmp]$ yum list installed |grep cx
python36-cx_Oracle.x86_64              8.3.0-1.el7                 @ol7_developer
[oracle@localhost tmp]$ yum list installed |grep instant
oracle-instantclient-basic.x86_64      21.8.0.0.0-1                @ol7_oracle_instantclient21
oracle-instantclient-release-el7.x86_64

[oracle@localhost ~]$ yum search cx_oracle
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
============================================================= N/S matched: cx_oracle ==============================================================cx_Oracle-12c-py27.x86_64 : Python interface to Oracle
cx_Oracle-py27.x86_64 : Python interface to Oracle
python-cx_Oracle.x86_64 : Python interface to Oracle
python-cx_Oracle-12c.x86_64 : Python interface to Oracle
python36-cx_Oracle.x86_64 : Python interface to Oracle

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
[oracle@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install python36-cx_Oracle.x86_64
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
Package python36-cx_Oracle-8.3.0-1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[oracle@localhost ~]$ python3
Python 3.11.0 (main, Nov 26 2022, 17:15:54) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44.0.3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cx_oracle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_oracle'
>>> quit()
[oracle@localhost ~]$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul  1 2022, 08:35:16) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44.0.3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cx_oracle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cx_oracle
>>> quit()

[oracle@localhost ~]$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
[oracle@localhost ~]$ python3 --version
Python 3.11.0
[oracle@localhost ~]$ which python
/usr/bin/python
[oracle@localhost ~]$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

[oracle@localhost ~]$ echo $PATH
/home/oracle/Desktop/Database_Track/coffeeshop:/home/oracle/java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/home/oracle/sqlcl/bin:/home/oracle/sqldeveloper:/home/oracle/datamodeler:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/oracle/sqlcl/bin:/home/oracle/sqldeveloper:/home/oracle/bin:/home/oracle/.local/bin:/home/oracle/bin
[oracle@localhost ~]$ echo $ORACLE_BASE
/u01/app/oracle
[oracle@localhost ~]$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u01/app/oracle/product/version/db_1
[oracle@localhost ~]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib/
[oracle@localhost ~]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH64
/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib/

[oracle@localhost ~]$ env
XDG_SESSION_ID=2
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
HISTSIZE=1000
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.59.1 65195 22
SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/2
USER=oracle
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib/
TWO_TASK=ORCL
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH64=/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib/
GNOME_CHECK=1
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/oracle
PATH=/home/oracle/Desktop/Database_Track/coffeeshop:/home/oracle/java/jdk1.8.0_201/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/home/oracle/sqlcl/bin:/home/oracle/sqldeveloper:/home/oracle/datamodeler:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/oracle/sqlcl/bin:/home/oracle/sqldeveloper:/home/oracle/bin:/home/oracle/.local/bin:/home/oracle/bin
PWD=/home/oracle
JAVA_HOME=/home/oracle/java/jdk1.8.0_201
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/oracle
LOGNAME=oracle
JAVAENV=true
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/home/oracle/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.59.1 65195 192.168.59.130 22
LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
TMZ=GMT
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/version/db_1
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Answer (score 2):

[Update: use the latest version of cx_Oracle, now called python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a)].

You now seem to have multiple cx_Oracle packages installed, which isn't helping untangle your problems (and not something I want to replicate).

To start from scratch with a clean OL7 image, follow the "Installing Python 3 from the Oracle Linux 7 Latest Repository" section of https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-python.html:

```
$ sudo yum -y install python3
```

and then the "Installing cx_Oracle for Python 3" section:

```
$ sudo yum -y install oraclelinux-developer-release-el7
$ sudo yum -y install oracle-instantclient-release-el7
$ sudo yum -y install python36-cx_Oracle
```

You can then use the driver:

```
cjones@localhost:~$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Nov 18 2021, 10:07:16) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44.0.3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cx_Oracle
>>> cx_Oracle.version
'8.3.0'
```

Update: as commented on by Anthony in another answer, make sure you use the correct case for `import cx_Oracle`.

If you install a version of Python or cx_Oracle that is not listed on the page, you will need to install cx_Oracle using 'pip' packages from PyPI instead of RPMs.  Note that cx_Oracle on PyPI currently has prebuilt packages up to Python 3.10.

Some other notes:

- You are setting ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  You should never set ORACLE_HOME with Instant Client.  And you don't need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH when using Instant Client 19 (or later) RPM packages.
- cx_Oracle 8 is only available for Python 3

**The latest version of cx_Oracle is now called python-oracledb**, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

To install python-oracledb on a clean OL7 machine:

```
sudo yum -y install python3
sudo yum -y install oraclelinux-developer-release-el7
sudo yum -y install python3-oracledb
```

You can then use it immediately in the new Thin mode without needing Oracle Instant Client:

```
cjones@localhost:~$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Nov 18 2021, 10:07:16)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44.0.3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import oracledb
>>> oracledb.version
'1.1.1'
```

(There are no casing or underscore issues with this new name!!)

To use python-oracledb in Thick mode, install Instant Client manually:

```
sudo yum -y install oracle-instantclient-release-el7
sudo yum -y install oracle-instantclient-basic
```

The python-oracledb RPMs are currently only available for the basic Python 3 version.  If you have other versions, then install python-oracledb with pip, see [the python-oracledb instructions Installing python-oracledb on Linux](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-python-oracledb-on-linux).

Comment: Thank you for your help. How can I specify which version of python this will be installed into? I have python 3.11 installed, but when I install cx_oracle I can find it in python 3.6.

Comment: There is no cx_Oracle (or oracledb) RPM for Python 3.11.  You will need to install using `pip` instead of `yum`, see the last link in my answer.

Comment: You would need to make sure you use the matching version of `pip`.  The easist way is with a command like `python3 -m pip install oracledb ...`

Comment: Thank you, Chris, I have been trying to use that command but I keep getting the below error even after installing ssl1.1.1.1
[root@localhost ~]# python311 -m pip install oracledb
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the SSL module in Python is not available.
because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/oracledb/

It is really never-ending, I run from one error to the next, and this whole Linux experience is fairly frustrating. So I really appreciate the kind strangers helping out.

Comment: I was able to install oracledb into python3.6 after fixing this error:(Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-pi3f_o_n/oracledb/). Upgraded pip and install easy install then it worked. I am frustrated that I can't get it into 3.11 but I need to stop wasting time. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Consider using Oracle Linux 8 or 9.  These might be easier to use - and will have a longer maintenance period.

Comment: I wish I could. I downloaded an Oracle appliance, a vm that already has all the oracle apps installed. I assume I could download and I install all apps on my own.

Comment: Perhaps look at https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/tree/main/samples/sample_container  and extend that?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the module is `cx_Oracle`, not `cx_oracle`. Note the case!

Comment: Well, I wish I can include a screenshot here, when I am in VScode I can use both without a problem. But from the terminal, you are right, case matters! Not sure why VScode is not complaining. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: It may be "helping" you out by looking for a module that is the same but with different case. :-)